# How can I start a Rails console with command line arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails app from major version 3 to 4. In the previous version we could tap into the boot process by passing a block to `config.before_initialize` in our `Application` class. From here I could specify options like `rails c -some_cool_switch` and have access to it from `ARGV`.

In Rails 4 I cannot even get to the pry line in this block as I'm getting the following error `invalid option: --foobar (OptionParser::InvalidOption)`.

I'm about to dive into the source code to figure out what I can do short of monkey patching and will report back. I was hoping that someone else has a better solution or at least an idea that I'm going up the wrong tree.

I can always fallback to so something like `SOME_ENV_VAR=some_cool_switch rails c` and just use another ENV var but I'd like to know my options and if this is the better approach or not.

## Reason this no longer works

The `railties` gem has changed. Previously on Rails 3 the command line arguments were not parsed until `start` was called on the `Console`. Now the command line is parsed before the app initializes and the options are strict so an error is raised.

## tl;dr

In Rails 4, is it possible to pass arguments to the console like `rails c --some_arg`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the arguments like below,

```
➜  test_app git:(master) ✗ RAILS_E=rails_test rails c -- --rails_env_test test
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> ARGV
=> ["--rails_env_test", "test"]
[2] pry(main)>
```

or

```
➜  test_app git:(master) ✗ RAILS_E=rails_test rails c -- --rails_env_test=test               
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> ARGV
=> ["--rails_env_test=test"]
[2] pry(main)>
```

Then you can process the ARGV to get the passed values. Please let me know if you need more on this.